# ReactJS form element values not displayed in chrome browser DOM inspector

Tags: reactjs

We created a component having form elements for e.g. text box

The problem is when we change the value of the input element the DOM inspector in chrome browser is not showing up the latest value.

Similar problem occurs with html select with options.

Is this a known issue? The problem is it is stopping Selenium from testing set /get methods.

Comment: i don't have any troubles reading the value of an input per ID/ClassName.  
did you use any form-plugins/libaries like MUI?

Answer (score 0):

try -> `ReactDom.findDOMNode()`
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/working-with-the-browser.html